# Leading Zeroes on Arduino Ethernet MAC Address

Tags: ethernet

How can I pass the MAC address to Ethernet shield with leading zeroes?

I change the default MAC address from `DEADBEEFFEED` to something like `DEADBEEFFE01`. So I only change the last number from `0xED` to `0x01`. My board is communicating to a separate server and when I look at the MAC in that server, my board is listed as `DEADBEEFFE1`.

It's not as simple as printing the MAC address with padded zeroes as the board is actually removing it.

I've looked at the Ethernet library and I saw that the mac is passed as an array of `uint8_t`. I think that's why, the last number is read as 1 (which is correct) but passed as just that.

Is there a way for the MAC to pass leading zeroes?

Comment: 0x01 is 1. the server prints it wrong

Comment: Yep, apparently, found out that it is the server that has a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Writing this in case someone in the future might be interested.

The values passed in the Ethernet library is correct. The last value, 0x01 must be 1 and is written correctly, `0x01` in the registers of the W5500 inside the Ethernet shield.

Where I've got it wrong is how I pass the MAC address to the server. I'm basically creating a string for a json message. In there, I've put `%02x` to make sure that zeroes are padded.